# A little math of projecting a sphere to cube faces

Tags: math

I am working on a program that creates cube faces out of an equirectangular image.

I divided the work in 2:
1) map the equirectangular image to a sphere
2) map the sphere to a cube face.

I have wrote a function which maps any point on the sphere to a point on the equirectangular image, so step 1 is completed.

for step 2, my approch was to take a cube which is inscibed into the sphere. both the cubeand the sphere are centered at the origin.

Take a point A on any face of the cube. The color of that pixel, I set it to be the color of the point on the sphere where the line OA intersects the sphere. (O is the Origin, so OA is like the viewing ray).

Look to what results I got:

[image]

And this is what I should have obtained:

[image]

You can see that my result is rounded, so I guess I am not mapping the sphere to the cube faces using a correct approch.

How should I map the sphere to the cube face?

Comment: As a side note, that is a cool looking bug.

Comment: well it's not a bug, I think I am not using the right approch in obtaining the projection. But I don't know an better way. This is why I hope somebody has a better ideea:)

Comment: Can you post some code?  Also, have you noticed that your image is flipped (bed on the right vs bed on the left)?  Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: well the code isquite long. And there is nothing wrong with the code. What I would like you to validate is the approch of creating the projection.

Comment: can you also post your starting image